# prove that graph G=(V,E) has at least |v|-|E| components

Tags: algorithm, discrete-mathematics

Prove that graph `G=(V,E)` has at least `|v|-|E|` components

I need answer for above question with example and full description.

Comment: Then maybe you should have paid more attention in class.

Comment: i took as a correspondence .so kindly request you to help us

Answer (score 0):

A graph with |V| vertices and no edges has exactly |V| components. Adding an edge can reduce the number of components by at most one (if the vertices that the edge is incident on were not previously connected by another path; otherwise, the number of components is not reduced). Therefore the least possible number of components after adding |E| edges is |V|-|E| and no graph of |V| vertices and |E| edges can have fewer than this many components.

Answer (score 0):

**Claim:** Each component `Ci` with vertices `Vi` has at least `|Vi|-1` edges.

**Proof:** The subgraph containing only `Vi` is connected, and the minimal connected graph is a tree, which has `|Vi|-1` edges. If `Ci` had less than `Vi-1` edges - it wouldn't have been connected, which is contradicting how we defined `Ci`.

Denote `Ei` the number of edges in component `Ci`.

Note that `sum{|Ei| for each Ci} = E`, since there is no edge connecting component `Ci` and component `Cj` (otherwise they would have been connected themselves).
Now, let's sum all of edges in all `Ci`, and we'll get

```
|E| =(1) sum { |Ei| } >=(2) sum{|Vi|-1} =(3) |V| - sum{1 | for each Ci} 
                                  =(4) |V| - #components
->
|E| >= |V| - #components
#components >= |V| - |E|
```

**QED**

Explanation for the equalities in the above proof:

(1) Comes from summing all edges in each component sums to `|E|`, since there are no edges that cross componentes (explained above)

(2) Comes from the claim we proved

(3) Summing |Vi| for all `Ci` results in `|V|`

(4) summing `1` for each component results in the number of components